# Android Unparseable date error

Tags: java, android, date

I actually wnat to find difference between the two dates but  get unparceable date error
at the curent date :

```
String act_dateString;

         Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance();
          act_dateString  = cal.getTime().toLocaleString();


        SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

        Date date_old = null;

            try {
                date_old = formatter1.parse(act_dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Logcat shows:

```
10-21 00:03:34.904: W/System.err(770): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Oct 21, 2013 12:03:34 AM
10-21 00:03:34.904: W/System.err(770):  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:645)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at com.example.datesdifference.MainActivity.showDifference(MainActivity.java:60)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at com.example.datesdifference.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-21 00:03:34.914: W/System.err(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
```

I have searched this on google but unable to resolve this. Can anybody help please ?

Comment: Why are you converting a date to a string, then parsing it back?  There is a simple rule in programming.  Only convert a date to a string when you want to show it to the user, store it somewhere that only stores strings or when passing it to another app.

Comment: Actually the act_dateString is the date stored in the Sqlite database  and returned in cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the output of `toLocaleString` does not match the format you use in `formatter1`, so a exception is thrown.

You should try to see what `act_dateString` looks like, then you know what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert calendar to Date then you can use this i believe

```
Date date_old =  new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String act_dateString;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date_old = null;
    act_dateString =formatter1.format(cal.getTime());
       try {
           date_old = formatter1.parse(act_dateString);
       } catch (ParseException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this way to parse the date. For example,In your code, calling toLocalString() will give you the String '**Oct 20, 2013 12:57:28 AM**'. This will throw **java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Oct 20, 2013 12:57:28 AM** You have to input a Date String with the format "yyyy/MM/dd". For that you have to convert the date format to the String format "yyyy/MM/dd". then, it will be able to parse the input String

```
  String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy/MM/dd";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
    String dateInStringFormat = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    try {
        //parsing the date string with format "yyyy/MM/dd"
        date = sdf.parse(dateInStringFormat);
        System.out.println(date.toLocaleString());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DateTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Hope you understand why the exception is thrown now. To find the difference between two dates in days,

```
   long diffInDays = (newerDate.getTime() - olderDate.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24);
   System.out.println(diffInDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Your input string is almost in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Replace the slash characters with hyphen characters.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2016/01/02".replace( "/" , "-" ) ) ;
```

Determining today’s date requires a time zone as the date varies around the globe by zone at any given moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. The [`Days`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Days.html) class represents a span of time as days.

```
int days = Days.between( ld , today ).getAmount() ;
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.